# open control panel using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

i'm very new to VBScript, i need to open control panel using VBScript,
I tried to open explorer like this

```
Dim txtFolderToOpen  
txtFolderToOpen = "C:\Windows" 
App.Run txtFolderToOpen 
Set App = Nothing
```

this works fine, but if i put the path as `Control Panel` it won't work,

Is there any way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: Do not hard-code paths like `C:\Windows` in your application. There is no guarantee that the system directory will be on the `C:` drive, nor that it will be named `Windows`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open the Control Panel, you can [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) the *%windir%\system32\control.exe* file:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "control.exe"
```

To open a specific Control Panel applet (.cpl), specify the .cpl file name as a parameter for control.exe:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "control.exe TimeDate.cpl" ' Open Date/Time properties
```

Comment: This is correct. Note that the reason it works is because the `%windir%\system32` directory is added to the `PATH` environment variable by default, which means that Windows will search there when provided with an unqualified path (like `control.exe`).

Comment: When I run this code, I get a **`Runtime error 70 : Permission denied`** error and the whole Excel crashes.

Answer (score -1):

To open Programs and Features using a vbscript, use the following command-

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "control.exe Appwiz.cpl"
```